# Duplicate rows in a data frame in R using 'mathematical combination rule' based on number of valid value for certain variables

Tags: r, insert, duplicates, data.table

I have a data frame like this and I would like to insert new rows under each row in a way that each row would be kind of duplicated of the original row based on a mathematical combination rule of the appearance of the T type variables' values and I also would like to get rid off the original rows. So the new rows would keep the values of the non T type columns (ID, P1, P2) but will change the values of the T type variables only having values in T1 and T2 columns as many time as the combination requires, so for 3 (e.g. a, b, c)   valid values in one row of the T type variables the combination would be 3 (ab, ac, bc) but for 4 (e.g. a, b, c, d) it would be 6 (ab, ac, ad, bc, bd, cd) etc. This means inserting 3 , 6 new rows).

```
ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
P1= c(10, 20, 30, NA, 19, 31, NA)
P2= c(8, NA,25,34,71,11,NA)
T1 = c("a", "a1", "e1", "d1", "a3", "f1", "f2") 
T2 = c("b", "b1", "a1", "b2", "a4", "f1", "f3")
T3 = c("c", "c1", "c1", "d2", "k1", "a4", "f9")
T4 = c( NA, "d1", "f2", "b3", "c1", "b3", "f5")
T5 = c( NA, NA, NA, NA, "d6", "a4", "f6")
T6 = c( NA, NA, NA, NA, "f4",  NA, "f7") 
T7 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "c1")
T8 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "c8")
T9 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "f1")
T10= c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "k3")

df1 <- data.frame(ID, P1, P2, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10)
```

So this is how the first couple of rows of my new data set would look like (computed from the first 2 rows of the original data frame):

```
ID = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)
P1= c(10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20)
P2= c(8, 8,8,NA,NA,NA,NA, NA, NA)
T1 = c("a","a", "b", "a1", "a1", "a1", "b1", "b1", "c1") 
T2 = c("b","c", "c", "b1", "c1", "d1", "c1", "d1", "d1")
T3 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
T4 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
T5 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
T6 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA) 
T7 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
T8 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
T9 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
T10= c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)

df2 <- data.frame(ID, P1, P2, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10)
```

This seems very challenging for me, it would be easier to insert only one row using a simpler rule. I only managed to figure out how to calculate the combinations, which formula is: (n*(n-1))/2 where n is the number of the T type valid values in a row.  Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was not initially written with `data.table` in mind, as that requirement came up later, and therefore simply converts `data` into `data.frame` before processing. There is bound to be a more appropriate DT way of doing this.

---

Probably not the most efficient solution, writing it off the cuff, but it seems to match your requirements.

Example dataset

```
library(data.table)

df1 <- structure(list(ID=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7), P1=c(10, 20, 30,
  NA, 19, 31, NA), P2=c(8, NA, 25, 34, 71, 11, NA), T1=c("a",
  "a1", "e1", "d1", "a3", "f1", "f2"), T2=c("b", "b1", "a1",
  "b2", "a4", "f1", "f3"), T3=c("c", "c1", "c1", "d2", "k1",
  "a4", "f9"), T4=c(NA, "d1", "f2", "b3", "c1", "b3", "f5"),
  T5=c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "d6", "a4", "f6"), T6=c(NA, NA, NA, NA,
  "f4", NA, "f7"), T7=c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "c1"), T8=c(NA,
  NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "c8"), T9=c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "f1"),
  T10=c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "k3")), row.names=c(NA, -7L),
  class=c("data.table", "data.frame"),
  .internal.selfref=NULL)
```

Functions

```
per_row_comb_fun <- function(rownumber, data, tcol) {
    rowi <- data[rownumber,]
    naix <- is.na(rowi)
    comb <- t(combn(rowi[!naix & tcol], 2))
    nrwc <- nrow(comb)
    nwdf <- rowi[rep(1, nrwc),]
    nwdf[,tcol] <- NA
    nwdf[,which(tcol)[1:2]] <- comb
    nwdf
}

comb_fun <- function(data, prefix="T") {
    data <- as.data.frame(data)
    rownumbers <- 1:nrow(data)
    ptrn <- paste0("^", prefix, "[0-9]+$")
    tcol <- grepl(ptrn, colnames(data))
    cmbl <- lapply(rownumbers, per_row_comb_fun, data=data, tcol=tcol)
    do.call(rbind, cmbl)
}

comb_fun(head(df1, 4))

#     ID P1 P2 T1 T2 T3 T4 T5 T6 T7 T8 T9 T10
# 1    1 10  8  a  b NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA
# 1.1  1 10  8  a  c NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA
# 1.2  1 10  8  b  c NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA
# 2    2 20 NA a1 b1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA
# 2.1  2 20 NA a1 c1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA
# 2.2  2 20 NA a1 d1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA
# 2.3  2 20 NA b1 c1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA
# 2.4  2 20 NA b1 d1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA
# 2.5  2 20 NA c1 d1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA
# 3    3 30 25 e1 a1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA
# 3.1  3 30 25 e1 c1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA
# 3.2  3 30 25 e1 f2 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA
# 3.3  3 30 25 a1 c1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA
# 3.4  3 30 25 a1 f2 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA
# 3.5  3 30 25 c1 f2 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA
# 4    4 NA 34 d1 b2 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA
# 4.1  4 NA 34 d1 d2 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA
# 4.2  4 NA 34 d1 b3 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA
# 4.3  4 NA 34 b2 d2 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA
# 4.4  4 NA 34 b2 b3 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA
# 4.5  4 NA 34 d2 b3 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA
```

Here's an alternative, much more lightweight and quick version that does away with the empty T-columns, and is entirely rigid with column order.

```
cfun <- function(data, prefix="T") {
    data <- as.data.frame(data)
    patrn <- paste0("^", prefix, "[0-9]+$")
    tcol <- grepl(patrn, colnames(data))
    na.rm <- function(x) x[!is.na(x)]
    fcomb <- function(x) t(combn(na.rm(x), 2))
    combs <- apply(data[, tcol], 1, fcomb)
    rreps <- data[rep(1:nrow(data), lengths(combs)/2), !tcol]
    combs <- do.call(rbind, combs)
    cbind(rreps, combs)
}

cfun(head(df1, 4))
#     ID P1 P2  1  2
# 1    1 10  8  a  b
# 1.1  1 10  8  a  c
# 1.2  1 10  8  b  c
# 2    2 20 NA a1 b1
# 2.1  2 20 NA a1 c1
# 2.2  2 20 NA a1 d1
# 2.3  2 20 NA b1 c1
# 2.4  2 20 NA b1 d1
# 2.5  2 20 NA c1 d1
# 3    3 30 25 e1 a1
# 3.1  3 30 25 e1 c1
# 3.2  3 30 25 e1 f2
# 3.3  3 30 25 a1 c1
# 3.4  3 30 25 a1 f2
# 3.5  3 30 25 c1 f2
# 4    4 NA 34 d1 b2
# 4.1  4 NA 34 d1 d2
# 4.2  4 NA 34 d1 b3
# 4.3  4 NA 34 b2 d2
# 4.4  4 NA 34 b2 b3
# 4.5  4 NA 34 d2 b3
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I receive this message: 
" Error in `[.data.table`(rowi, !naix & tcol) : 
  i is invalid type (matrix). Perhaps in future a 2 column matrix could return a list of elements of DT (in the spirit of A[B] in FAQ 2.14). Please report to data.table issue tracker if you'd like this, or add your comments to FR #657." Do I need to require any library to run this function?

Comment: @Malna: Are you testing it on `df1` as it is described in your question?

Comment: Yes, I tested on both, on my dummy data frame and on the real one and both cases I received this message.

Comment: @Malna: Have you tried it in a fresh workspace? You're getting a `data.table` error while there is nothing of that in either the dataset or code, so there might be a variable or function conflict, meaning two objects sharing the same name.

Comment: A friend of mine could solve the problem using Python. It looks like this:
TCols = [col for col in df.columns if 'T' in col]
otherCols = [col for col in df.columns if 'T' not in col]

newRows = []

for rix in df.index:
    for i in range(len(TCols)-1):
        for j in range(i+1, len(TCols)):
            newRows.append(df.iloc[rix][otherCols].to_dict())
            newRows[-1]['t1'] = df.iloc[rix][TCols[i]]
            newRows[-1]['t2'] = df.iloc[rix][TCols[j]]

newdf = pd.DataFrame(newRows)

Anyone has an idea how to translate this code to R?

Comment: My Python skills are very limited, so sorry, no. But I'm positive that there's something funny about your environment, or maybe something went wrong when you copy/pasted the code. It works perfectly fine on tio.run (added link to my answer)

Comment: In your code "^T[0-9]+$", T should be the name of the column which we want to search in (without the numbering) and [0-9] is for 10 columns?

Comment: No, it's a [regex pattern](https://regexr.com/4f7h3). It matches any column name that starts with a capital T, followed by one or more digits, and nothing more.

Comment: OK, thanks. Then I do not understand why it does not work on the real data set. Anyway, thanks, your answer is actually good and working, I will figure out how to make it work on my data set.

Comment: @Malna: I refactored the code, making it a little neater and easier to use. I figured maybe you didn't modify it appropriately when you applied it to your other data. Now if you read in the two functions and then call `comb_fun(data)`, where `data` is the name of your data.frame, it should work. But I'd advise you to test it out first with `comb_fun(head(data))`, as the output can get big rather quickly.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer did not work on a data with the class data.table. So altering the code provided by @AkselA, we worked out a solution which works on a data.table type (alternatively you can change the class of your data to data.frame and the first code will work). (Note that the "NameofColumn" refers to the name of those columns which you want to apply the combination for and you have to use in the code the name which are the same for each of these columns and which are followed by a number (see an example in the dummy data frame).

```
per_row_comb_fun <- function(rownumber, data, tcol) {
  rowi <- data[rownumber,]
  rowil <- as.list(rowi)
  naix <- is.na(rowil)
  comb <- as.data.frame(t(combn(rowil[!naix & tcol], 2)))
  nrwc <- nrow(comb)
  nwdf <- rowi[rep(1, nrwc),]
  nwdf[,which(tcol)] <- NA
  nwdf[,which(tcol)[1:2]] <- comb
  nwdf
}

comb_fun <- function(data) {
  rownumbers <- 1:nrow(data)
  tcol <- grepl("^NameofColumn[0-9]+$", colnames(data))
  df1.l <- lapply(rownumbers, per_row_comb_fun, data=data, tcol=tcol)
  do.call(rbind, df1.l)
}

YourData_output <- comb_fun(data=YourData)
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize that the `T` wasn't fixed. What's the actual rule for column names? Can `NameofColumn` be anything, including `P`, or are `P` columns always numeric?

Comment: I updated the code to allow for easy change of prefix. I don't think your vector theory is very plausible, but just in case I added the result of `dput(df1)`, It's identical to what's described in your question.

Comment: Thanks, haha my 'vector theory' actually very plausible on our data. Try your code with an existing data set and you will see. The T type columns are characters, the rest of my data is integer. The naming is obviously different but that was not an issue here. Without your code we would not be able to solve the problem and only needed little changes because tcol gave us a logical vector and comb a matrix. So when we updated comb to a data frame and used 'which' to identify the position of the tcol columns then all worked fine. I still left your solution marked as a good and right answer. Thanks

Comment: "tcol gave us a logical vector and comb a matrix", that is the expected behaviour. `tcol` is a logical vector, with a `TRUE` for every column index that matches the pattern, and `FALSE` for the rest. After the transpose `comb` will definitely be a matrix.

Comment: Oh, maybe you have some rows where all, or all except one, of the T columns are `NA`? That would mess things up. But In a different way I suspect.

Comment: But if there's something about your data that breaks my code, could you share that? Use `dput()`, and `head()` to limit the size.

Comment: Sorry I do not know why your code did not work on our data. I am not able to share it but there are no all NAs in T type variables. We tested your code line by line and this is how we figured out what to change and those were the issues.

Comment: Well shucks. Your data is `data.table` isn't it, not `data.frame` as stated in the question. That's why you got that `Error in '[.data.table'(rowi, !naix & tcol)` early on. I converted `df1` into `data.table`, tested it on my code, and got the exact same error message. Then tested it on your modified code and it worked fine.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It 's class actually data.table and data.frame. I had to use library data.table for computing something before. I am very new to R and still learning, did not even realise that because of this I changed the class of my data. Sorry about any confusion, I update my answer saying this code working for data.table. Thanks again.

Comment: This is one of the reasons why we prefer to use `dput()`, that way we get an exact replica.

Comment: I see, next time I will get dput and will anonymize my data example accordingly. :)